# what database structure needed to associate a company for selecting type and sub type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

right now i have three `model` 
**Company, Commodity and SubType**

```
class Commodity < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :sub_types
end

class SubType < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :commodity
end
```

Now a Company can select a commodity from a list and after that it
 will select the sub types . so what field are required for that to track in database. i think that `has_many :through` is required for that but not sure **how to track both commodity and sub type selected by the company**

Comment: Question, is the sub type to commodity one to one (I know that's what you have in your question, just double checking)? If so the association will be taken care of. As for the Company to Commodity relationship check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: @Patrick a sub_type belongs_to only one commodity and a commodity can have many sub_types . now user will be able to select a commodity and then select sub type with in the provided sub type for that commodity

Comment: so let see if I understand your structure. A `Company` can have many `Commodity`s, a `Commodity` can have many `Company`s, a `Commodity` can have many `SubType`s, and a `SubType` can only have one `Commodity`. Is that correct? If that's the case then a many-to-many relationship between 'Companies' and 'Commodities' is the way to go, but which type depends on your needs. Do you need to store information about the association? You can get a `Company`s `SubType`s through the `Commodity`s as @amit_saxena said.

Comment: @Patrick you are going right just need a little modification. commodities has_many sub_types. now Company first select a commodity and then select sub type from the available sub types for that company. What amit saxena solution says that a company have all sub types of the commodity selected

Comment: Sorry for the pause. One more question, can a `Company` only have one `SubType`, which I understand is taken from the `SubType`'s provided via the selected `Commodity`. The reason I ask is the selection of the `SubType` could be handled through the controller and view and a reference column for the `SubType` record id added to the `Company` model or a one-to-many relationship between `Company` and `SubType`.

Comment: No a company can have many sub_types .

Comment: I think what you want is http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Company and Commodity have a one to many relation (and not many to many), you can do the following:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :commodities
has_many :sub_types, :through => :commodities
end

class Commodity < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :sub_types
belongs_to :company
end

class SubType < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :commodity
end
```

`company_object.sub_types` will give you all the sub types for a given company using the above relations.

Comment: a company can select specific sub type for a company . thats what i required . finding all sub_type for a commodity is simple one

Comment: I don't exactly get what you need here, but to get specific sub_types of a given commodity, you can use `company_object.commodities.where(:name => "Commodity Name").first.sub_types`. If you can explain with an example, I can try and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the best bet is going to be a Polymorphic Association

```
class SubType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization, polymorphic: true
end

class Company< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subtypes, as: :organization
end

class Commodity< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subtypes, as: :organization
end
```

Then you will be able to reference `@company.subtypes`, `@commodity.subtypes`, as well as `@subtype.organization`

Read through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations
I hope that this helps

Comment: No thats not the case. May be i am not able to explain properly what i need . MY BAD

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood